# python, lib : ImportError: No module named lib.options

Tags: python-2.7, lib, anaconda3

I'm using lib and I tried to import the BaseOptions from lib.options in python:

`from lib.options import BaseOptions`

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./apps/eval.py", line 13, in <module>
    from lib.options import BaseOptions
ImportError: No module named lib.options
```

from the way I see  i didn't have lib package, i tried to download it through:

`conda install lib`

then i got this error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - lib

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

then i tried this command to install lib:

`pip install lib`

after that i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./apps/eval.py", line 13, in <module>
    from lib.options import BaseOptions
ImportError: No module named options
```

I'm using Anaconda3 and python 2.7.

after that i tried to upgrade my python to python3.7 through:

```
conda install python=3.7
```

but i failed and got a lot of conflicts.

any Idea how could I fix this?